# Parser throwing a function as an error when querying MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I've been writing a program and have come across an error that Google brings no results for. I'm using async.series to do multiple queries sequentially. However, my first query returns a really weird error that Google returns no results for. Any help is appreciated!

Error:

```
    C:\path_to_root_project_folder\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:78
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^
 function () {
    var args = arguments,
        index = -1,
        length = nativeMax(args.length - start, 0),
        array = Array(length);

    while (++index < length) {
      array[index] = args[start + index];
    }
    index = -1;
    var otherArgs = Array(start + 1);
    while (++index < start) {
      otherArgs[index] = args[index];
    }
    otherArgs[start] = transform(array);
    return apply(func, this, otherArgs);
  }
```

Code:

```
async.series([
        function(callback){ //generate uuid
            console.log("generating uuid..");
            newUuid = uuid(); //these are also defined
            console.log("$$$$$$$$$$$$ " + email); //email is defined in the function this async series is nested in
            callback(null);
            return;
        },
        function(callback){
            console.log("$$$$$$$ querying email");
            pool.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE INSTR(email, '" + email + "') > 0", function(err, rows){  //I think it errors out here?
                if(err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                if(rows[0] != null){
                    res.json({ //res is defined
                    status: 200,
                    success: "EmailExists"
                });
                res.end();
                duplicate = true; //duplicate is defined
                callback(err);
                }
                callback(err);
            });

        }], function(error){if(error) throw err;});
```

EDIT: After further investigation with breakpoints I discovered the error was further down, in another SQL query. For some reason, the error being thrown is "[object Object].

Code: (this is after the last async series in my original code

```
function(callback){

        pool.query("SELECT * FROM chapters WHERE INSTR(school, '" + school + "') > 0", function(err, rows){
            if(err) throw err;
            debugger;
            callback(rows);
        });  
    },
```

Comment: Your query, while being prone to SQL injection, actually looks logically correct.  Can you step through your code with a debugger to see what is happening?

Comment: what's in `err` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen After messing around with the debugger for awhile, I found the error was actually being thrown from further down the code. I've edited the post with the relevant code and error.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your SQL, could be a typo of some sort as the query string looks fine, so your `throw` statement terminates the program. According to MDN :

> The throw statement throws a user-defined exception. Execution of the
>   current function will stop (the statements after throw won't be
>   executed), and control will be passed to the first catch block in the
>   call stack. If no catch block exists among caller functions, the
>   program will terminate.

I suggest you either add a catch block, or just log your error, and you'll be able to see what's going on.

Comment: The exact same SQL query (literally copy pasted) works in another function. Also, it still gives the same error when I use "SELECT * FROM users", which shouldn't have any possibility of a typo. I also checked that my table is called "users".

Comment: what's in the error object? can you pst the full err stack and related lines/functions? It's definitely strange

Comment: JSON.stringify the error and it won't be obj object ;)

Comment: The object that is thrown is the result that's returned from the SQL query. I don't understand why it's placing the results in err though? Every example I've seen shows it being (err, results).

Comment: Hmm, it actually seems that the error occurs at callback(rows). Any idea why this occurs?

Comment: I changed the callback to callback(err, rows) and it worked, but the next function in the series with parameters (err, rows, callback) returns both err and rows as undefined, despite calling back with rows in the previous function.